# Control de código, para desarrolladores

Tags: django, git, administración-de-software

Buen día
Tengo una duda, de cual es la mejor herramienta de  controlar el código a las desarrolladores.

Tengo un proyecto en desarrollo con 5 personas,  que trabajan colaborativamente (Git), pero no quiero que todos vean el código completo, solo una persona tenga el control y las otras únicamente las partes/módulos que se le asignen.

En el  proyecto usamos VSCode, Django, con Git.

Usando Git, todos tienen el mismo codigo, como se puede restringir parte de este?.

Comment: Hola! Esta pregunta está basada en opiniones y posiblemente termine cerrada. Lo cual hace inexplicables los votos positivos jejeje. Además, ya están usando Git (tú lo dices en la pregunta), entonces no se entiende el problema.

Comment: Gracias, tienes razón, ya formule un poco más la pregunta.   En realidad, no se como controlar desde Git: que solo unos desarrolladores accedan a ciertas partes, por ejemplo el desarrollador 1, solo pueda entrar a catálogos, el desarrollador2  a procesos (pero no a catálogos), etc

Comment: Git no funciona de esa forma. Te tienes que bajar el proyecto entero porque el control se hace en cada pc, no centralizado... De todas formas, parece que lo que queres hacer son librerias para tu sistema.. por lo tanto cada una estaria en un git diferente?

Comment: eso, estoy pensando, dividir el proyecto, el tema que tengo entonces es la integración al proyecto principal

Answer (score 0):

El tema del *control* que tienen las personas sobre el código no es de git per se, es de flujo. Digamos que yo soy el "lead" y yo se cuales son las secciones sobre las que cada quien es un taco sin competencia. Si alguien me pide hacer un pull request y veo que esta tocando un archivo sobre el que hay otra persona que se las sabe todas, en git puro podría pedir que le hagan un sign-off a las revisiones.... en github/gitlab podría pedirle a la persona que mire el código y le de la bendición antes de aceptarlo.